# Реализация поиска по сайту

Tags: поиск, search, php, mysql

Сразу скажу, что я новичок в этом деле. Суть проблемы заключается в след.
Не обрабатывается поисковый запрос. Все заполнял верно (Пользователя, базу, пароль и проч.)
Где ошибка?

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

if (!mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS)){
    exit('Ошибка: <b>Не удалось подключиться к серверу</b>');
}
if (!mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)){
    exit('Ошибка: <b>Невозможно подключиться к базе данных!</b>');
}

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

function search ($query)
{
    $query = trim($query);
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

    if(!empty($query))
    {
        if(strlen($query)<3){
            $text = '<p>Слишком короткий поисковый запрос</p>';
        } else if(strlen($query)>128) {
            $text = '<p>Слишком длинный поисковый запрос</p>';
        } else {
            $q = "SELECT 'id', 'news', 'image' FROM 'news' WHERE 'text' LIKE '%query%' OR 'news' LIKE '%query%' OR 'images' LIKE '%query%' OR 'id' LIKE '%query%'";

            $result = mysql_query($q);

            if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

                $text = '<p>По запросу <b>'.$query.'</b> Найдено совпадений: '.$num.'</p>';

                do {
                    //Запрос на получаение ссылки
                    $q1 = "SELECT 'id' FROM 'news' WHERE 'id' = '$row[id]'";
                    $result1 = mysql_query($q1);

                    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0) {
                        $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

                    }

                          $text .= '<p><a href="'.$row1['id'].'/'.$row['icon'].'</a></p>
                    <p>'.$row['name'].'</p>';

        } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
        } else {
            $text = '<p>По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.</p>';
        }
    }   
} else {
    $text = '<p>Задан пустой поисковый запрос.</p>';
}
return $text;
}
?>
```

Comment: @Аноки, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3):

[`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

> Чтобы получить количество рядов, возвращённых SELECT-запросом, используйте функцию `mysql_num_rows()`.

**UPD**:Не оборачивайте названия полей в кавычки. Если и нужны то такие `

Зачем последний запрос?

Используя `LIKE` фильтруйте только текстовые поля (`CHAR`,`TEXT`)

Comment: Пробовал, все равно выдает, что ничего не найдено.